# Update Firmware SSD Samsung Evo 840 from a MacPro Late 2013

Tags: mac, ssd, software-update, firmware

My SSD Samsung Evo 840 is getting slow and heat, so I'm trying to update its firmware from a MacPro Late 2013. I downloaded the ISO provided by Samsung (Samsung_SSD_840_Series_DXT09B0Q_Win_Mac), burned it to a disc, but when I try to boot from it (holding Alt/Option when the Mac starts - tried hold C too) the computer doesn't see the CD drive with the bootable image.
I tried to do that with a USB stick too, but without any success.

Comment: On phone so can’t find linked Q but I never managed it. Clone the drive, reformat to NTFS, put it in a PC, update, reformat, clone back.

Comment: I did this: put the SSD in a PC desktop, directly in SATA port, installed Magician and updated the firmware. Everything is okay now. Thanks!